# How to get hard disk size in bytes on Windows 2000?

Tags: c, windows, hard-drive, ioctl, windows-2000

How can I get the exact size of the hard disk in bytes on the old Windows 2000?

IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO works fine for volumes, but not on physical disk handles (stuff at //./PHYSICALDISKx) on Windows 2000. (Works fine for physical drives from XP or later)

We still have to support this ancient OS...

UPDATE:

The code is written in C, so I would use plain Windows API if possible.

Comment: In what manner does that ioctl not work?  I assume it fails with a specific error code?  Have you tried any of the other ioctls (GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT, GET_LENGTH_INFO, etc)?

Comment: @Luke On Windows 2000 it gives ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION when I use it on a handle I got by opening a drive at //./PHYSICALDRIVEx. It works fine on XP later. So I'm looking for a workaround for that OS. Getting the exact number of bytes on disk is a requirement.

Comment: You can get this with IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY.  It gives you cylinders, tracks per cylinder, sectors per track, and bytes per sector.  Multiply them all together and it gives you the total number of bytes for the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no IOCTL that give you the exact hard drive size on Windows 2000.

But there is a workaround, that worked:

I used [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get cylinders, tracks/cyl, sectors/track, bytes/sector.

Multiplying them gave me a rough size of the HDD but not the exact size (little smaller). I can calculate the almost last sector id from this.

To get the exact size I used [IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and sent [SCSI read commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_Read_Commands) to attempt to read beyond the end of disk, so I had a sector number for a non-existing sector, then used binary search to get highest sector id where the read succeeds.

Multiplying it with the bytes/sector, I have the exact size of hard disk in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the free space in C (without any API or etc)

If you run "`dir c:\`", the last line will give you the free disk space.

Better solution: "`fsutil volume diskfree c:`"

Or try the below code...

```
void main (int argc, wchar_t **argv)
       {
          BOOL  fResult;
          unsigned __int64 i64FreeBytesToCaller,
                           i64TotalBytes,
                           i64FreeBytes;
             fResult = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx (L"C:",
                                     (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64FreeBytesToCaller,
                                     (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64TotalBytes,
                                     (PULARGE_INTEGER)&i64FreeBytes);
             if (fResult)
             {
                printf ("\n\nGetDiskFreeSpaceEx reports\n\n");
                printf ("Available space to caller = %I64u MB\n",
                        i64FreeBytesToCaller / (1024*1024));
                printf ("Total space               = %I64u MB\n",
                        i64TotalBytes / (1024*1024));
                printf ("Free space on drive       = %I64u MB\n",
                        i64FreeBytes / (1024*1024));
             }
       }
```

Comment: The [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627131/getdiskfreespaceex-reports-wrong-number-of-free-bytes) is inaccurate.

I want to know the size of the whole disk: all partitions and unallocated space included. We need to write disks directly and want to know the last valid sector number on the whole disk.

Comment: @Calmarius Whoah - low level operations without a heavy textbook. Bold!

Comment: @PP. There is no other way to remove those pesky boot viruses, that place their stuff into the last sectors... ;)

Comment: @Calmarius remove.. or install?

Comment: @PP FDISK /MBR will do.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to get this type of info, I typically use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as it provides a wealth of data on just about anything.

Comment: It's a layer above IOCTL calls isn't it?