# Get %ROOT% size in Python

Tags: python, size, directory, os.walk

Is there a better way to get the root size instead of using os.walk?

```
import os    

def get_size( start_path='.' ):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size    

print get_size("C:/")
```

I'm trying this code(which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)), it works fine inside folders, not that fast, but when I try it in the root directory it's super slow or sometimes it crashes [WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect]. Is there a way to get the root size just like left cliking properties in C:\?

EDIT:
I tweaked a little bit the code to avoid the errors.

```
fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
try:
    stat = os.stat(fp)
except OSError:
    continue

try:
    seen[stat.st_ino]
except KeyError:
    seen[stat.st_ino] = True
else:
    continue

total_size += stat.st_size
```

But it still slow as hell. It takes 6~7 minutes to calculate it.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python

Comment: It's the same link I provided.

Comment: I would look into os calls.  `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx()` comes to mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get `pywin32` (the Python for Windows Extensions) from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). Then, you can do this:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> lpFreeBytesAvailable, lpTotalNumberOfBytes, lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes = win32api.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx('C:\\')
>>> lpTotalNumberOfBytes
300061552640
```

This value (in bytes) is equal to 279 GB, which is the size of the C drive on my machine. Note, however, the caveats in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28VS.85%29.aspx) (reproduced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/627777/1535629) with emphasis), which may or may not be relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 3):

You want to access the operating system call to get the free space of a volume.

In Python 3.3 and above it's called `shutil.disk_usage`. For older versions of Python, on Unix people suggest various things like calling the external `df` utility, but that won't work on Windows. It seems the best answer is to call the win32 API function `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`. Take a look at this email:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-July/010640.html

The code appears below:

```
from ctypes import c_ulong, byref, windll

freeBytesAvailable = c_ulong()
totalNumberOfBytes = c_ulong()
totalNumberOfFreeBytes = c_ulong()

# Ansi version:
windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceExA('c:\\', byref(freeBytesAvailable),
byref(totalNumberOfBytes), byref(totalNumberOfFreeBytes))
```

You can also call the Unicode version `GetDiskFreeSpaceExW` if you have a Unicode file name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a cross-platform solution, you may want to try **psutil**.

They claim they support:

> "… **Linux**, **Windows**, **OSX**, **FreeBSD** and **Sun Solaris**, both **32-bit** and **64-bit** architectures, with Python versions from **2.4** to **3.4** by using a single code base."

I just tried this in a terminal window on a Mac:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> d = psutil.disk_usage('/')
>>> d.free
230785544192
```

and it gave me the correct information.
Their website and docs can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/).